# How to write connect user/password in procedure in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to create a procedure to allow the user (with the username 'c##administrator' and password 'addm')to login into the oracle using the connect <user_name>/<password_name> like this. But it said that [click here to see the errors that oracle said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMSrS.jpg). When I try to detect what is wrong on my script, I realize that the script cannot execute the command `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'connect c##administrator/addm;';`  and said that it is invalid sql command :<. But I don't know why it said that. I'm sure my password and my username is both correct.

Please help me fix it :( Thank you so much

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE system.SYS_KTraTaiKhoanAdmin (adUsername IN varchar2, adPassword IN varchar2)
IS
    ex EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF (adUsername != 'c##administrator' AND adPassword != 'addm') THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('PLEASE LOG IN AGAIN');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('LOG IN SUCCESSFULLY!');
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'connect c##administrator/addm;';
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN ex THEN
           Raise_application_error(-1, 'Error');
END;
/
BEGIN
  system.SYS_KTraTaiKhoanAdmin('c##administrator', 'addm');
--rollback; 
END;
/
```

Comment: `connect` is a `SQL*Plus` command.  It can't be used in PL/SQL.  `SQL*Plus` is a client side program.  PL/SQL is a server side programming language.  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  A user obviously has to be logged in before they can call a stored procedure so it doesn't really make sense to log in again inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering it. The reason why I did it because I want to create an app for managing employee and this app is only used by the admin of the management employee system. As you can see, the name is c##administrator. I want to the admin must login to the app first before he can use it. Can you recommend another way to do this? I use sql developer to run this procedure

Comment: Either the application would connect to the database using whatever credentials the user provided (presumably the `c##administrator` username and password) or the application would connect to the database as an application user (what generally happens with three-tier applications, the connection pool is defined using a single user).  If the application is an APEX application, you can have users log in to the APEX application using their Oracle database credentials.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have just remember something when talking to you. I can use the grant command in the procedure and it run successfully. Does "grant command" is a SQL*Plus?

Comment: Did you put the hard-coded admin password in your procedure?

Comment: Yes. I created it like this by system account
``` CREATE USER c##administrator IDENTIFIED BY addm;
GRANT connect, create session to c##administrator;
GRANT  ALL PRIVILEGES to  c##administrator WITH ADMIN OPTION CONTAINER = ALL;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO c##administrator;
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO c##administrato; ```

Comment: `grant` is a SQL statement.  It is DDL so if you want to put it in a procedure, you'd need to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate` or `dbms_sql`).  It is pretty unusual to want to grant permissions in a procedure-- that's normally something that you would do as part of the promotion process when new objects are created or when new users need to be provisioned.  Maybe this procedure is part of the user provisioning process?

Comment: You have hundreds of security functions on Oracle - **use them**! Don't re-invent the wheel which is highly insecure in your case.

Comment: What is the purpose of this procedure? The user needs to have admin username and password, so why should he not login directly as admin?

Comment: When you search for "how can I force a specific client in Oracle" you will see that you cannot achieve it. Example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233525/how-to-prevent-specific-applications-from-connecting-to-oracle

Comment: Also bear in mind, once you are connected like this you can simply modify this procedure, because you granted `DBA` role.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have realized that the way I did before was wrong. Thank you so much for helping me to realize this fact.